# How to solve Error in visual studio code of setting flutter in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout, flutter-web, vscode-debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPPYL.jpg)
This error here of installation and installing vs code of flutter

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&passive=false&cid=2030. flutter 2.10 support windows. we need visual studio desktop development

Comment: You have to install [Visual Studio IDE](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com) to enable windows application development. I think you might have mistaken it with Visual Studio Code a.k.a VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

> **Visual Studio** is different than Visual Studio Code.

You should install [Visual Studio IDE](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) to solve this warning.
Flutter 2.10 supports windows development and requires visual studio for desktop development.

Answer (score 0):

From the **computer's settings** go to **Update & Security** then **for developers** then **open the developer mode**, hopefully it will be done.

**Restart Your IDE & cmd.**

[image]

**Otherwise** change flutter version 2.10.1 **Thank You..**